# How do I install a library for c++ on macOS?

Tags: c++

Im new to c++ and I need to install this library: https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus
So that I can communicate to a UR5e robot. How do install everything that is needed and the library? How do I check if I have installed everything?

Comment: Take a look Installation here https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus#installation

Comment: Yes, following the provided instructions is a great place to start.

Comment: In fact, this is borderline off-topic, as it's not about any issues with the library installation, but more closely resembles a "What's wrong with my code?" type question.